# IDataErrorInfo not firing in case of int column DataGrid

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, idataerrorinfo

I have a DataGrid with a Column that is binded with an 'int' type property. I am using IDataErrorInfo for validation. My validation rules are working fine they get fired as soon as I change value of a cell. Let's say user enter value less than 0, I show respective error in the tooltip. Problem comes when user clear the value of text box. In that case IDataErrorInfo never fires and as a result I cannot show user validation error through tooltip saying that value cannot be empty. DataGrid makes the red border around textbox, which is fine, and a '!' sign at row header, but no validation error in the tooltip as IDataErrorInfo never got fired. Is there anything I can do to fire IDataError info in case value of textbox is cleared?

**Edit:**
XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayOrder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DisplayOrder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

DisplayOrder Property

```
public int DisplayOrder
{
    get
    {
        return m_DisplayOrder;
    }
    set
    {
        if(value != m_DisplayOrder)
        {
            m_DisplayOrder = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DisplayOrder");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should post your bindings and show us your itemssource object. i assume that your property you bind to is type of int, so if you clear the textbox, wpf binding try to set the int property to null. there a binding error happens cause your int is not nullable. and because of the binding error your idataerror has no chance to fire cause it would not be invoked. you can try to add ValidatesOnExceptions=true to your datagrid column binding to see an error.

Comment: Even if I add 'ValidateOnExceptions=True' IDataErrorInfo is not fired and I don't see any message in the tooltip either

Comment: activate binding errors for debugging and look to your output window to see binding errors. there you should find some more information. i really think the problem is your type of int. when you clear your textbox wpf try to set null to int and this cause an exception(and your setter gets not called!). ValidateOnExceptions=True should give you the information also, but maybe you have to check your validation template for your datagridcell.

Comment: change your type to Nullable<int>, just to see wether your setter gets called or not.

Comment: First of all.. even if I use `Nullable<int>` instead of `int` the setter is not called when I clear value, otherwise setter is called every time.

Comment: Getting this exception when I clear textbox value in output window 
`System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=DisplayOrder; DataItem='MyClass' (HashCode=8773737); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)`

Comment: `at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'`

Comment: I understand that IDataErrorInfo is not firing because of binding error.. my question is how can I tell user about error in this case? I am currently using string property instead on int as a workaround.. but wanted to know if there is any proper way to handle this..

Comment: well one way would be to use a string property like you do now. you can then easily set idataerrorinfo when String.Empty.(btw thats the way i do in my apps) ValidateOnExceptions=True should also work, at least you should see a red border around your cell. if you have no tooltip with the error message, try to create a validationtemplate for your cell.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from error, StringToNumber converting is throwing, can u try to use your own IValueConverter to convert String to Int and other way around. and maybe by default it will convert empty string to 0 (where your IDataErrorInfo should kick in and show error)